# Is it possible to solve equations containing Laplace transforms in Open Modelica?

Tags: modeling, modelica, openmodelica

I'm using [Open Modelica](https://openmodelica.org/) for developing models and the governing equations have Laplace terms. Please give the link to the library if available. Also, it'd be better if I could write the script by myself.

Comment: Not solving, but could be inspiration: http://blog.xogeny.com/blog/fourier-analysis/